# Javascript. Как отправить сообщение функции, в другом скрипте, на выполнение?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Господа, доброго времени суток. Прошу вашей помощи. Пишу расширение для хрома. Есть 2 скрипта `Background.js` и `Content.js`.
В Background есть функция которая после выполнения скрипта, обновляет предыдущую страницу

```
function handleTabRemoved(tab) {
    updateTabsCount();
    chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
}
```

в Content функция активирует нажатие на кнопку на странице сайта.

```
function handleTabClick() {

        setTimeout(function()   {
                document.getElementById('0').click();
        }, 5000);
}
```

Как оформить Нажатие кнопки после обновления страницы `chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);`?
Знаю что оформить нужно как-то через sendMessage, но не до конца понимаю как это сделать правильно. В JS новичок, только учусь, прошу сильно не бить палками. :)

Comment: Может неправильно понял, но content же у вас впишется сам в страницу после обновления и соответственно навесит событие на кнопку.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Только проблема в том, что он слишком хорошо работает ) А именно, нажимает на кнопку не только после обновления страницы, но и при её открытии вручную. Забыл добавить... Есть страница с 2мя кнопками. 1ая кнопка ведет на главный сайт, 2ая на сайт со статистикой. И мне не всегда нужно что бы кнопка нажималась, а только после обновления через функцию в Background

Comment: Хочу сделать примерно так, что бы при выполнении background, отправлялся запрос на выполнение в Content. Но не знаю как сделать правильно. 3 дняь мучаюсь, лажу по сети.... Примеров много, но мне не хватает знаний что бы подбить все под себя.

Comment: А зачем вы обновляете предыдущую страницу? какая там логика ?

Comment: Это связано с авторизацией. На сайте клиенты для авторизации используют смарт карты. Разработчики.... Если их можно так назвать, написали программу которая при активации карты в кардридере, открывает страницу с авторизацией и авторизирует. Так же при извлечении карты, открывается новая страница и выходит из аккаунта. Я решил пока что написать расширение которое будет закрывать вкладки и обновлять предыдущую страницу после закрытия. Но нужно нажимать на кнопку после того как смарт карта активирована.

Comment: Получается там запускается процесс. Карта активирована, открывается вкладка, после авторизации вкладка закрывается, страница обновляется, кнопка нажимается. Проблема в том что когда запускается браузер со страницей или открывается страница вручную, кнопка нажимается в любом случае, а нужно только после обновления страницы через скрипт.

Comment: Вы подгружаете контент с стронних ресурсов ? если да, то почему не используете AJAX ? Просто при перезагрузке страницы всё начинается заново ))

Comment: Стыдно признаться... Мало знаний. Только начал изучаение JavaScript и в будущем возможно расширение будет переписано более мягко и гибко. Но на данный момент дело срочности...

Comment: Не надо стыдиться )), просто трудно помочь т.к логика полностью не понятна, я могу привести пример как отправлять и получать Message. просто незнаю насколько это решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Я думаю стоит попробовать ) Буду очень благодарен за пример!

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки и получения `Message` используйте данную логику:

> Background.js

```
function handleTabRemoved() {
began()    
}

function began() {

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      greeting: "hello"
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log(response.msg) /*При необходимости получаете ответ*/
    });
}
```

> Content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello"){
    handleTabClick();
/*Можете отправить ответ, если необходимо*/

      sendResponse({
        msg: "Update"
      });

    }

  });
```

ЗЫ: хорошо бы протестировать, написал по памяти ))

Comment: Что-то не доходит. Даже alert не выводит...

Comment: @BeleK0ss сделайте проверку без перезагрузки, просто запустите handleTabRemoved(), и проверьте в console.log();

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, в консоль вообще ничего не выводится. В отладчике расширения пишет "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://gjbjlfmibeieoajjpddlekilgchggmeb/background.js:56:28" и вроде как по ссылке указывает на console.log(response.msg) /*При необходимости получаете ответ*/

Comment: Хорошо, удалите строку console.log(response.msg)

Comment: Теперь тихо ) handleTabRemoved();
undefined
began()
undefined

Comment: как это undefined ? ))) что то там не так ))

Comment: Если запускать вот так то работает handleTabRemoved
ƒ handleTabRemoved(tab) {
    updateTabsCount();
 
 began();
 }

Comment: Странно, вроде все правильно. В background.js `function handleTabRemoved(tab) {
    updateTabsCount();
 began();
 }
 
function began() {

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.msg); /*При необходимости получаете ответ*/
    });
}` в conent.js `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello"){
    alert('111');
/*Можете отправить ответ, если необходимо*/

      sendResponse({msg: "Update"});

    }

  });` И не работает....